EC2 migration across AZ
I understand that an EC2 instance can be migrated across AZ.
When we stop an ec2 instance, its private ip address,which comes from subnet, is retained. When we migrate instance to another AZ, which has different subnet, then wont it cause issue?

Your assumption is right. When you move an EC2 instance to another Availability Zone (AZ) in AWS, it usually means changing to a new subnet(just as you mentioned), since each subnet is tied to a specific AZ.
This also means that the instance will get a new private IP address from the range defined for the new subnet. This is because IP addresses are tied to subnets and cannot move between them.
While an Elastic IP does not resolve the change of the private IP address when moving across subnets, it can help maintain a consistent public IP address. This can be useful if external access is needed and you want to minimize disruption.
